# How do I get @media screen to scale down my button?

Tags: html, css

I have a button that has a width of 300px and a height of 130px. I want the button to scale down with the page as you change the size of the browser. When I added @media screen and made the max width 375px, about the screen size of an iphone, the button remained the same size. Can anyone help?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  all: unset;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 17px;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  top: 51%;
}

#button {
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #58cc02;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 0 #58a700;
}

#button:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

.stroke {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 17px;
  outline: #58cc02 solid 3px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  animation: pulse 1.5s infinite alternate;
  top: 51%;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.20);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:375px) {
  #button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button id="button"></button>

  <div class="stroke"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case, you need to use vw, vh instead of px in width and height property to change width and height according to scree size.

Answer (score 2):

Testing your code, the button does get smaller at <375px, although your stroke effect styled onto your div   does not.

A quick and easy fix would be to add .stroke to your CSS within the media-screen tag.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  all: unset;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 17px;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  top: 51%;
}

#button {
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #58cc02;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 0 #58a700;
}

#button:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

.stroke {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 17px;
  outline: #58cc02 solid 3px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  animation: pulse 1.5s infinite alternate;
  top: 51%;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.20);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:375px) {
  #button,
  .stroke {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button id="button"></button>

  <div class="stroke"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the button and stoke noticeably smaller? While they do sale down it does not appear  that way, even when I change the width and height dimensions it look the same size.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When the width of the page goes below 376 pixels, it gets noticably smaller.
You say "about the screen size of an iphone", have you simply assumed that most iPhones has a 375px width? That seems to be the size of an iPhone SE, while most other current gen iPhones are bigger.

Comment: Yeah, your media query is much too small to appear on an iPhone. With pixel ratios they have a width roughly the same as a laptop monitor. That's a different question, though, and many answers exist explaining it.

Comment: Sorry if I was not being clear. For reference I want the button to be about this size https://www.mobicip.com/content/how-block-youtube-completely-0  The size of the YouTube logo as it relates to the screen size of the iphone. When I run the code the size of the button is not this small.

Comment: Firstly, as Isherwood said in their answer, you should look into using dynamic values. Secondly, a quick fix for your problem seems to be to change the max-width in the media query to ~500px

Comment: Thank you for all your help! By changing the media query value to 500px I was able to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the whole hassle by using a pseudo-element (`::after`) rather than additional markup. It'll automatically follow the button size. You could also set the button size itself to a dynamic value (vw, vh, %, rem) to make it infinitely resizable instead of using media queries.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  all: unset;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 17px;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 51%; */
}

#button {
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #58cc02;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 0 #58a700;
}

#button:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

#button::after {
  content: '';
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 17px;
  outline: #58cc02 solid 3px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  animation: pulse 1.5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.20);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:375px) {
  #button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button id="button"></button>
</div>
```